# Use Electron-App (displaying an online Website) as a secure proxy to the local network

Tags: security, electron

I've build a Web-App that is displayed in an Electron-App with [Nativefier](https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier). That already works great, but now i need to send requests from the website to the local network to talk with some local devices which are (with it's ip-address) configured in the Web-App.

I had the idea to use the Electron-App as a "proxy" to the local network by using a javascript callback from the Website to the Electron-App (don't know if this is possible, just an idea), which then makes the local request because it's running on a computer in the same network.

The reason for this post is that i need ideas/tips to secure this and prevent allowing to talk to other than the desired Web-App (available under a certain domain) by developing something protective like checking or validating the Server, validating the request by sending it's hash back to the server or other methods.

So my questions are: is it generally a good idea to do something like this or is this a huge security problem and have anyone any tips to secure the communication and only allowing the communication to in the web-app configured devices in the local network?